# Spark - Have I read from csv correctly?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I read a csv file into Spark using:

> df = spark.read.format(file_type).options(header='true', quote='\"',
>   ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace='true',inferSchema='true').load(file_location)

When I tried it with sample csv data from another source and did diplsay(df) it showed a neatly displayed header row followed by data.

When I try it on my main data, which has 40 columns, and millions of rows, it simply displays the first 20 column headers and no data rows.

Is this normal behavior or is it reading it wrong?

Update:
I shall mark the question as answered as the tips below are useful. However my results from doing:

```
df.show(5, truncate=False)
```

currently shows:
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ |��"periodID","DAXDate","Country Name","Year","TransactionDate","QTR","Customer Number","Customer Name","Customer City","Document Type Code","Order Number","Product Code","Product Description","Selling UOM","Sub Franchise Code","Sub Franchise Description","Product Major Code","Product Major Description","Product Minor Code","Product Minor Description","Invoice Number","Invoice DateTime","Class Of Trade ID","Class Of Trade","Region","AmountCurrencyType","Extended Cost","Gross Trade Sales","Net Trade Sales","Total(Ext Std Cost)","AdjustmentType","ExcludeComment","CurrencyCode","fxRate","Quantity","FileName","RecordCount","Product Category","Direct","ProfitCenter","ProfitCenterRegion","ProfitCenterCountry"| +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I shall have to go back to basics an preview the csv in a text editor to find out what the correct format is for this file to figure out what's going wrong. Note, I had to update my code to the following to deal with pipe delimter:

```
df = spark.read.format(file_type).options(header='true', quote='\"', delimiter='|',ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace='true',inferSchema='true').load(file_location)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is normal beheaviour. The dataframe function [show()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show%20show()) has a default value to display 20 rows. You can set a different value for that (but keep in mind that it doesn't make sense to print all rows of your file) and also stop it from truncating. For example:

```
df.show(100, truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for Spark dataframes to display limited rows and columns. Your reading of the data should not be a problem. However, to confirm that you have read the csv correctly you can try to see the number of rows and columns in the df, using

```
len(df.columns)
```

or

```
df.columns
```

For number of rows

```
df.count()
```

In case you need to see the content in detail you can use the option [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922140/10465355) by [cronoik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6664872/cronoik).

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal behaviour. You can view the content of your data in different ways:

**`show()`**: Show you in a formatted way the first 20 rows. You can specify as argument the number of rows you want to display (if you provide a value much higher that your data is ok!). Columns will be truncated too, as a default configuration. You can specify `truncate=False` to show all the columns. (like @cronoik correctly said in his answer).

**`head()`**: The same as `show()`, but it prints the date in a "row" format. Does not provide a nice formatted table, it is useful for a quick complete look of your data, for example with `head(1)` to show only the first row.

**`describe().show()`**: you can show a summary that gives you an insight of the data. For example, shows you the count of elements, the min/max/avg value of each column.